# new htaccess .html rule causing redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please can someone help, we are having problems with our htaccess.

We have created a rule sending everything ending .html (our product pages) to our details.cfm page. However after creating this rule our admin area subdirectory is redirecting to the index page.

Have we set this up properly? I think we have an error here

```
# Rewrite rules for non www entrances
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.ourdomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourdomain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]


# Rewrite rules - new rule
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /Details.cfm?ProductUrl=$1 [NC]

# Rewrite rules - current rules
RewriteRule (.*)-sku-(.*)$ /Details.cfm?Name=$1&ProductCode=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)-shop-(.*)$ /Results.cfm?bname=$1&Brand=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)-cat1-(.*)$ /SubCat.cfm?catname=$1&category=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)-cat2-(.*)$ /SubSubCat.cfm?secondcatname=$1&secondary=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)-cat3-(.*)$ /Results.cfm?thirdcatname=$1&third=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)-shop$ /ResultsShop.cfm?bname=$1 [NC]

# Rewrite rule - If no extension specified use cfm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.cfm -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.cfm

# Rwerite rule - 404 redirect rule
ErrorDocument 404 /cferror.cfm

# Gzip rule to speed up website with image caching
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

We also have an htaccess file in the directory which checks for a htpasswd

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Admin"
AuthUserFile "/home/ourdomain/.htpasswds/public_html/v3/passwd"
require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?v3/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/v3/$1 [R,L]
```

Thankyou!

Comment: For which URL do you get 404 or 500 error?

Comment: thanks for the reply :-) when we go to ourdomain.co.uk/v3 @anubhava it redirects to the root

Comment: So problem is that you're getting infinite redirection loop OR just want to fix this unwanted redirection?

Comment: @anubhava just to fix the unwanted redirection, we want to exclude this directory from redirection please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line:

```
# skip v3 from rewrite
RewriteRule ^v3(/.*)?$ - [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thankyou @anubhava but it doesn't work. when we remove this rule it works again # Rewrite rules - new rule
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /Details.cfm?ProductUrl=$1 [NC]

Comment: That rule has no link with `/v3` URL. Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before that rule.

Comment: After further investigation in the v3 directory we also have another htaccess file so we use htpasswd

Comment: Difficult to read code from comments. Edit your question and provide this information there.

Comment: not really, just need secure passwd protection @anubhava